# Odoo 10 - Mail Templates Change Color and Bottom Odoo notice

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am creating a new email template by following this link.

However when email is received I get I get more an Odoo message and colored upper and bottom areas with the document reference, logo, and company info

How and where can I change the color of the areas and change the bottom notice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the following template: (Sale Order Notification Email)

Look into the CODE VIEW button and change colors inside.

It worked for me.

Check this HTML code using WHITE COLOR instead of purple.

```html
                
                
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ededed" style="padding: 20px; background-color: #ededed" summary="o_mail_notification">
                    <tbody>

                      <!-- HEADER -->
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="min-width: 590px;">
                          <table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="min-width: 590px; background-color: rgb(255,255,255); padding: 20px;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                              <td valign="middle">
                                  <span style="font-size:20px; color:#555; font-weight: bold;">
                                      ${object.record_name}
                                  </span>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle" align="right">
                                  <img src="/logo.png" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 80px;" alt="${user.company_id.name}">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <!-- CONTENT -->
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="min-width: 590px;">
                          <table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="min-width: 590px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 20px;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr><td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #555; font-size: 14px;">
                                ${object.body | safe}
                              </td>
                            </tr></tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <!-- FOOTER -->
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="min-width: 590px;">
                          <table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="min-width: 590px; background-color: rgb(255,255,255); padding: 20px;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                              <td valign="middle" align="left" style="color: #555; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px;">
                                ${user.company_id.name}<br>
                                ${user.company_id.phone or ''}
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle" align="right" style="color: #555; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px;">
                                % if user.company_id.email:
                                <a href="mailto:${user.company_id.email}" style=" color: #555;">${user.company_id.email}</a><br>
                                % endif
                                % if user.company_id.website:
                                    <a href="${user.company_id.website}" style=" color: #555;">
                                        ${user.company_id.website}
                                    </a>
                                % endif
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: hi there i've tried this, but the header and footer still default odoo, any idea why?? please help :(